# Get time difference reliably - Android

Tags: java, android

Given a Posix Time from the server (on application start I get the time in seconds) I want to send to the server the elapsed time after an event in the most reliable way.

These are the steps I made:

1. Get the Posix Time
2. Click on a button and get the true timestamp, which is to add elapsed time to the server time (can not rely on client side)
3. Send to the server the event's Posix Time

I used Java.Date, however I am pretty sure this is easily gullible. Imagine between the step 1 and 2 I change the clock.

Now other concern is to measure the time even if the phone is idle.

**So my real question is how can I measure reliably a time difference in android.**

I searched in stackoverflow but all examples I found were with date.

Comment: Have you heard about Timer in Android? try that

Comment: @Deepakkaku yes I know, however I thought that class had problems when the phone is in idle. Is it reliable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using [SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime()) or [SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtimeNanos()) depending on the precision you want.

[SystemClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html) is guaranteed to be monotonic and will continue to tick even when the CPU is in power saving mode.

Comment: This looks to solve all my problems, thank you. 
http://sangsoonam.github.io/2017/03/01/do-not-use-curenttimemillis-for-time-interval.html

From this reference "This includes time spend in sleep such as CPU off, display dark, and etc." 

However what's the diference between `SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()` and `System.nanoTime()`? I know the first is within Android Library and the second is "Vanilla" Java however is any real difference?

Comment: @Exprove This is definitely better than my suggestion of using `System.nanoTime()`. I didn't realize this before, but the origin time for `nanoTime()` is unique to the VM. If the framework kills your app in the background, you may have a different origin time when it resumes.